# Legendre transform of solution of heat equation

Tags: convex-analysis, heat-equation

Let $v = v(t,y)$ be a strictly convex $C^{1,2}((0,T]\times \mathbb{R})$ function such that

- It solves the heat equation: $v_t = \frac{1}{2} v_{yy}$
- $v_y(t,\cdot)$ has range $\mathbb{R}$.

Define a function $u$ via
$$ u(t,x) = \inf_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\{v(t,y)-xy\}$$.

**My question: what is the regularity of $u$ in both variable $t$ and $x$?**

I was able to get $u(t,\cdot)$ is twice-continuously differentiable, through strict convexity of $v(t,\cdot)$ and the inverse function theorem.

Comment: I expect that $u$ is strongly convex in $x$ since $v$ is twice differentiable in $y$ and hence Lipschitz-smooth. That you were able to show twice continuous differentiability just from strict convexity is surprising, you must have used other properties of $v$ I think?

Comment: @TonyS.F. I think strictly convexity gives you continuous differentiability of $u$. Direct computations show $-u_x(t,v_y(t,y)) = y$, so the derivatives are inverse to each other. Inverse function theorem then gives you two-time continuous differentiability. Am I correct? I would like to know what can we say on regularity in the variable $t$.